# Provide the steps to configure Route 53 failover with elb on aws without giving downtime

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53, failover

Can anybody provide me the Provide the steps to configure Route 53 failover with ELB on AWS without giving downtime

Comment: From your question it is not clear what you have and what you are trying to accomplish. Can you edit your question with more details?

Comment: Just I need to know. Step to configure Route 53 failover when we have two Elastic load balance in two different region end point.  And web site still be access by end user,  if any of the elb will become unhealthy.

Comment: Can any body help me to provide the steps to configure Route 53 failover when we have two Elastic load balance in two different region end point. And web site still be access by end user, if any of the elb will become unhealthy.

Comment: Failover will only happen when there is downtime. Your request cannot be accomplished. You should be using your ELB / ALB to manage instance failures and not Route 53.